# Get the current response headers set in a Tornado request handler

Tags: python, tornado

The Tornado `RequestHandler` class has `add_header()`, `clear_header()`, and `set_header()` methods. Is there a way to just see the headers that are currently set?

My use case is that I am writing some utility methods to automatically set response headers under certain conditions. But I want to add some error checking in order to not add duplicates of a header that I do not want to have duplicated.

I want to write come code that is more or less like this:

```py
class MyHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def ensure_json_header(self):
        if not self.has_header_with_key('Content-Type'):
            self.set_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')

    def finish_json(self, data):
        self.ensure_json_header()
        return self.finish(json.dumps(data))
```

But of course there is no `has_header_with_key()` method in Tornado. How can I accomplish this?

**EDIT**: this turned out to be an X-Y question. The real answer was to just use `set_header` instead of `add_header`. I am leaving this up for anyone else who might come along with a similar question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no documented api for listing the headers present in a response.

But there is a `self._headers` private attribute (an instance of [`tornado.httputil.HTTPHeaders`](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httputil.html#tornado.httputil.HTTPHeaders)) which is basically a dict of all headers in the response. You can do this to check a header:

```
if 'Content-Type' in self._headers:
    # do something
```

---

As an addendum, if you want to access all headers of a request, you can do `self.request.headers`.

---

Edit: I've opened an [issue about this](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/issues/2989) on github after seeing your question; let's see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Tornado will always have the `Content-Type` header set as it is in the default headers (https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/_modules/tornado/web.html#RequestHandler.clear). So if you want to ensure you have a specific content type set, just call `set_header`.

If you want to check that the response does not have a header set in **your code**, you’ll have to first reset the default header, which you can do by implementing `set_default_headers` and do a `clear_header(“Content-Type”)` there.

But you could also achieve the same by setting a property on your handler (say `override_content_type`), set that in code and then do a non conditional `set_header` before rendering the result.

Comment: Is Tornado smart enough to not return two separate `Content-Type` headers if I add one when one is already present? If so, that makes the whole question moot.